# Android tiled image offset

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm making a space game, and background is a tiling image of stars
If I want the image to scroll in various directions by using some offset value, how would i do that?

Currently, it just shows static tiled image.

This is how I create tiling Paint object:

```
    pBack = new Paint();
    pBack.setShader(
            new BitmapShader(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            getResources(),
                            R.drawable.space_seamless
                    ),
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT
            )
    );
```

Then i do this to render it

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), pBack);
```

Comment: what happens if you change the `0, 0, ...` to some other coordinate?

Comment: It shifts, revealing black background if positive, but if negative then it shows more tiled image.

Comment: and what if you add or subtract that same delta from the width and height?

Comment: Adding delta will keep background in a same position, but will crop delta amount. Reducing delta does nothing to the bg. Basically, once i set the shaders, they are fixed i guess

Comment: Anyway... a distant background will appear fixed. I guess you can apply a parallax effect to the in between layers.